# What Ws-Federation Endpoint is required for Identity Providers when using Thinktecture Identity Server V2 Federation?

Tags: ws-federation, sts-securitytokenservice

We are using IdentityServer V2 as our Identity Provider using WsFed/SAML2. We now want to federate. I tried adding our WsFederation endpoint as one of the Identity Providers but can't seem to get it to work.

When I add the STS itself, it won't work work... see results below for each WsFederation URL I've tried:

```
 https://localhost:44306/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
    (this just opens the federation xml page)
 https://localhost:44306/issue/wsfed
    (this just opens a blank page and doesn't prompt for credentials)
 https://localhost:44306/issue/wstrust/mixed/username
    (same as above - blank page)
```

Can the Identity Server V2 use its own WsFed endpoint as one of the identity providers or do I need to host it separately to be able to use it? If so, what URL do I use for the WsFederation Endpoint?

**UPDATE:** This was resolved...  Specifically:

1. Each Identity Provider needs to point to the '/issue/wsfed' endpoint (for WsFederation anyway)
2. Each WsFederation Endpoint needs to have a Relying Party configured which points back to the federating STS
3. Each Relying Party above needs to have the realm name of the federating STS (not the client RP)
4. Each Relying Party above needs to have the return URLs set to the '/issue/hrd' endpoint for the federating STS (NOT the client RP)

Once I configured everything like this, it worked.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - but have you tried the github wiki and issue tracker before?

Comment: I've read the [wiki](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/wiki) and watched the [Vimeo video](https://vimeo.com/51666379) on how to do this but when I follow those steps, I'm getting the behavior expressed above. Not sure why the WsFederation Endpoint URLs are not working.

Comment: This is resolved, see update inline above.